# storing cookies in client js and reading in java

Tags: java, javascript, json, cookies

I have stored a js array(key value pair) in cookie using JSON.stringify...

Ex:

```
var a={"aaa":"111","bbb":222};
document.cookie="mycookie="+JSON.stringify(a);
```

When I'm reading the cookie from js it returns the value for mycookie as a string {"aaa":"111","bbb":222} so I can parse it again using JSON.parse() and it works fine for me.

My need is to get the same cookie from java.. so I used HttpServletRequest's request.getCookie() method. It returns an array of cookies.. while iterating in to that, it does not have the cookie as "mycookie" instead of that it contains the following cookie list

```
cookie[0]= aaa:
cookie[1]= bbb:
```

why it does not return a value as

```
cookie[0]= mycookie:{"aaa":"111","bbb":222}
```

how does the getcookie method parses a single cookie in this mannar..

JS:

```
var dateOfVisiting=new Date().getTime().toString();
    var mycookie =  {‘page’:’example.com’,‘date’:dateOfVisiting};        
var expiryDate = new Date();
    expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime()+(30*24*60*60*1000));        
var expires = "; expires="+expiryDate.toGMTString();
    document.cookie="mycookie="+JSON.stringify(mycookie)+expires+"; path=/;"
```

Java

```
  Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
  String myData = null;
  for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
  System.out.println(cookie.getName()+“:”+cookie.getValue());
    if(“mycookie”.equals(cookie.getName())){
    myData = cookie.getValue();
    }
  }
```

The result is

page:
date:

And its not getting inside the if condition

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: edited @Murugan Pandian